# CSS from Classes not being applied to nav content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the content in my Bootstrap Nav tabs. The CSS classes are being applied but none of the styling shows.

The HTML (took out the other tabs for readability)

```css
.unpublished {
  background-color: $green !important;
  color: red;
}

//also tried this
.tab-content {
  .unpublished {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs course-tabs" id="course" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                <span class="fas fa-info-circle"></span>
                About this course space</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

 <div class="tab-content unpublished">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <div class="unpublished">
                <span class="fas fa-times-circle"></span>Course space is not published
                <a href="#">Publish course space in Canvas arrow-right</a>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using sass variables.
Make sure all the sass setup is correct. By that I mean the main.scss and all the partials that you are using are working fine. If not fix that fixed and try again.

Also the bootstrap CSS link (or CDN link) must precede our local custom stylesheet file to over-ride the default styling applied by bootstrap.

A quick tip though, whenever you find yourself in such a condition where your styling is not being applied and many such things, You must inspect code in  Developer Window (Ctrl+shift+I on windows and check the styling.

It's the best way you can learn and resolve your issues by yourself.

Thank you

Comment: welp that was it... I am definitely ashamed to have forgotten that after doing it a few times already. Thanks to you and everyone else (who had the right answers for different problems)

Comment: Keep moving forward! Try Try Again. And never give up. freecodecamp is a great place to learn for beginners. Let me share the link with you as well. https://learn.freecodecamp.org/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you're getting `$gray-medium` as a color but changing that to gray will make the background color work. Perhaps your styling precedence is off and the styles for the `a` tag are overwriting them. Making styles for the `a` tag will successfully style the links in your HTML.

```css
.unpublished {
  background-color: gray !important;
  color: red;
}

//also tried this
.tab-content {
  .unpublished {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: red;
  }
}

a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs course-tabs" id="course" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                <span class="fas fa-info-circle"></span>
                About this course space</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

 <div class="tab-content unpublished">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <div class="unpublished">
                <span class="fas fa-times-circle"></span>Course space is not published
                <a href="#">Publish course space in Canvas arrow-right</a>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gray-medium is a color defined in the code, changing it to any other color still doesn't work

Comment: It does work for me too... maybe the problem is a bootstrap rule with `!important` overwriting yours. Wouldn't be the first time I see Bootsrap doing that kind of shit (sorry for the swearing). First check the debugger to see if your CSS property is stroked-through and use its search to filter by property so yo can see where is the rule that overwrites yours. You can always try changing bootstrap clases for custom ones to check if the problem persist or test your code to look for syntax errors such as open tags and things like that. Sorry, but I can't help you more without seeing the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to style the first div, you should use this.

```
.tab-content .unpublished {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs course-tabs" id="course" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="fas fa-info-circle"></span>
            About this course space</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

css

```
 .unpublished {
      background-color: grey;
      color: red;
    }
```